# JPA skip persisting a specific property when persisting the Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity

I have a property in an Entity that I would like JPA to not persist.

I don't want to use @Transient as I would still like the property to be populated during READ. But the property should not be written when persisting the Entity. Is it possible?

Here is the property I would like not to be persisted by read

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private UserBare user;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you want a read-only attribute, but I'm guessing you might have tried this already and did not like the results?

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String myProperty;
```

Comment: Hi. Yes!! The property is currently decorated that way. I have edited my question to show the property declaration.

Comment: ...and what kind of result are you getting from that?

Comment: It is still persisting it. I suspect CASCADE.ALL. I'll try modifying the cascade statement and see if that helps.

Comment: Its really help me. I am really in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cascade = CascadeType.ALL. If you want specific use other types except ALL, MERGE and PERSIST.